# only half of output added into temp file

Tags: python

this is the code I'm working on

```
remote_conn_pre = paramiko.SSHClient()
remote_conn_pre
remote_conn_pre.connect(ip, 
username=username,password=password,look_for_keys=False,allow_agent=False)
remote_conn = remote_conn_pre.invoke_shell()
output = remote_conn.recv(1002)
remote_conn.send("\n")
remote_conn.send("enable\n")
remote_conn.send("show ip int brief\n")
remote_conn.close()
time.sleep(2)
output = remote_conn.recv(65535)
print output
output_cap = tempfile.TemporaryFile(output)
print output_cap
```

the output I got was:

```
 Traceback (most recent call last):
 File "p1.py", line 27, in <module>
 output_cap = tempfile.TemporaryFile(output)
 File "/usr/lib/python2.7/tempfile.py", line 488, in TemporaryFile
 return _os.fdopen(fd, mode, bufsize)
 ValueError: mode string must begin with one of 'r', 'w', 'a' or 'U', not '

 R1#enable
 R1#show ip int brief
 Interface                  IP-Address      OK? Method Status                
 Protocol
 FastEthernet0/0            192.168.2.101   YES other  up                    
 up '
```

how can I pass the output I can get from my code into a temporary file?

Answer (score 1):

`tempfile.TemporaryFile()`'s first parameter is `mode`, not the data you want to write.

Answer (score 0):

To write to a file

```
fo = open("filename.txt", wb)
fo.write(output)
fo.close()
```

mode "wb" writes the file in binary, creating a new file if it doesn't already exist, and overwrites the file if it does exist.